# jooq query nested object

Tags: java, sql, jooq

with jOOQ's amazing [Multiset Operator](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/) we are able to query and map nested lists into pojo objects. Now I try to find a way to also map a single nested object. So for example, I have a composed custom pojo class like:

```
public class CourseComposite {
  private String courseName;
  private Teacher teacher;
  private List<Student> students;
  ...
}
```

and I want to query and fetch it in one single step. So my current working solution is:

```
static final List<? extends Field<?>> TEACHER_SUB_COLUMNS = Arrays.stream(TEACHER.fields()).map(f -> f.as("teacher." + f.getName())).collect(toList());

List<CourseComposite> getCourses() {
  return this.ctx()
      .select(COURSE.NAME.as("courseName"))
      .select(TEACHER_SUB_COLUMNS)
      .select(multiset(selectFrom(STUDENT).where(STUDENT.ID_COURSE.eq(COURSE.ID))).as("students"))
      .from(COURSE).innerJoin(TEACHER).on(COURSE.ID.eq(TEACHER.ID_COURSE))
      .where(...)
      .fetchInto(CourseComposite.class);
}
```

That includes a preinitialised Field list `TEACHER_SUB_COLUMNS` with the purpose, to somehow tell JOOQ to map the Teacher object from "teacher.*" columns.

I am now wondering if there is a slightly more intuitive solution in this regard. I have tried to work with the row operator, but got no working solution so far.

e.g.

```
List<CourseComposite> getCourses() {
  return this.ctx()
      .select(COURSE.NAME.as("courseName"))
      .select(TEACHER_SUB_COLUMNS)
      .select(row(TEACHER.fields()).as("teacher"))
      .select(multiset(selectFrom(STUDENT).where(STUDENT.ID_COURSE.eq(COURSE.ID))).as("students"))
      .from(COURSE).innerJoin(TEACHER).on(COURSE.ID.eq(TEACHER.ID_COURSE))
      .where(...)
      .fetchInto(CourseComposite.class);
}
```

Maybe someone has a tip? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from jOOQ 3.17 and [#4727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727), `Table<R>` now extends `SelectField<R>` to allow for conveniently using `Table` expressions directly. With that in place, you can write things like:

```java
Result<Record3<String, TeacherRecord, Result<StudentRecord>>> result =
ctx().select(COURSE.NAME, TEACHER, multiset(...))
     .from(...)
     .fetch();
```

Comment: I saw that now Table<R> extends SelectField<R> now (probably this answer can be updated). However what if the Teacher table is named differently like TEACHERS. The mapping seems not working. I tried to use TEACHERS.as("teacher") but the I get an exception: missing FROM-clause entry for table "teacher"

Comment: @SGiux: I'll update the answer, thanks. Please can you ask a new question? It's not really related, and the comment section won't suffice to show what you're doing *exactly*.

Comment: here we go -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76604478/jooq-query-nested-object-with-different-name-than-table