# Jooq query nested object with different name than table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a problem really similar to the one described [jooq query nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090417/jooq-query-nested-object). To summarize I have this pojo:

```
public class CourseComposite {
  private String courseName;
  private Teacher teacher;
  private List<Student> students;
  ...
}
```

and I'm using the Jooq `DefaultRecordMapper` to map the record to the pojo, having the following query:

```
    ctx().select(
            COURSE.NAME.as("courseName"), 
            TEACHERS, 
            multiset(selectFrom(STUDENT).where(STUDENT.ID_COURSE.eq(COURSE.ID))).as("students")
          )
          .from(COURSE).innerJoin(TEACHERS).on(COURSE.ID.eq(TEACHER.ID_COURSE))
          .where(...)
          .fetchInto(CourseComposite.class);
```

However teacher is not mapped (the teacher field is null). I think it's because my postgresql table is called `teachers` and not `teacher` (this is the only difference with the stack overflow question mentioned above).

I tried to write:

```
ctx().select(COURSE.NAME.as("courseName"), TEACHERS.as("teacher"), multiset(...))
```

however in this case I get an exception:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "teacher"

Is there a way to tell jooq that `TEACHERS` should be binded to the `Teacher teacher` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "expected", though admittedly, a bit weird, because you're really aliasing a `Table`, not a `SelectField` (the API is the same). The fact that you're aliasing `TEACHERS.as("teacher")` *only* in the `SELECT` clause for that particular purpose is not known to jOOQ. You might as well use the alias like any other table alias. Think about it this way:

```java
Teachers teacher = TEACHERS.as("teacher");
```

Now, you'd be using it as follows:

```java
ctx().select(..., teacher, ...)
```

jOOQ can't just assume you meant for the alias to apply *only* in the `SELECT` clause. What if you added it to your `FROM` clause as well, as indicated by PostgreSQL's error message? I.e.

```java
innerJoin(teacher)
```

Because then, it would make sense to project the `teacher` alias reference, not the `TEACHERS` table reference. You might argue that jOOQ could detect what's The Right Thing™, because you clearly didn't include `teacher` in the `FROM` clause, but there can be many edge cases, especially when you have both (via self-join).

So, the solution is to just use `teacher` in the `FROM` clause, instead of `TEACHERS`.

#### Alternatives

You can obviously work around the problem by moving the mapping into the query, at least in parts, using an [ad-hoc converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/). You could write:

```java
TEACHERS.convertFrom(r -> r.into(Teacher.class))
```

In that case, the mapping from the `TeachersRecord` to your `Teacher` class would happen *before* trying to map the nested record into the parent object. It's also worth thinking about removing the reflection based `DefaultRecordMapper` entirely, and turn your objects into records:

```java
public record CourseComposite(
  String courseName, 
  Teacher teacher, 
  List<Student> students
) {}
```

Now, you can use `fetchInto(Records.mapping(CourseComposite::new))` at the end of your query, all type safe!